# Handlebar.js precompiled templates; what does it mean?

Tags: templates, compilation, express, handlebars.js

I'm a bit confused to what it actually means to have [precompiled Handlebar.js templates](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html). Since handlebar requires data i.e `<tag>{{title}}</tag>` which I am sending through Express.js what would it mean to even have precompiled templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiling in this context means converting your template string into a Javascript function. For your example the resulting function body would be something like `return '<tag>' + title + '</tag>'`. This is faster than using regular expressions to process the template. It also means the compiled templates can be used in the browser without the whole Handlebars library.

Comment: Ah I see. So that means the templates that I use in Express.js are not compiled, and they get compiled at runtime when that specific page is called?